# Error while downloading Talib for Final Year Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I wanted to install Talib in order to write code for KDJ indicator. However, I couldn't install it.

I already downloaded the file from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, and wrote `pip install Talib` in Anaconda prompt, but then it comes out error below:

```
  ----------------------------------------
 Failed building wheel for talib
  Running setup.py clean for talib
Failed to build talib
Installing collected packages: talib
  Running setup.py install for talib ... error
    Complete output from command "C:\Users\Jun Yap\Anaconda3\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\JUNYAP~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dgdxm9b0\\talib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JUNYAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w0546kkg\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\JUNYAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dgdxm9b0\talib\setup.py", line 47, in <module>
    'talib = talib.cli:cli',
      File "C:\Users\Jun Yap\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Jun Yap\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Jun Yap\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\JUNYAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dgdxm9b0\talib\setup.py", line 20, in run
    raise Exception("You probably meant to install and run ta-lib")
Exception: You probably meant to install and run ta-lib
dgdxm9b0\\talib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\JUNYAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-
record-w0546kkg\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JUNYAP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dgdxm9b0\talib\
```

Can I know whether there is any other ways to install Talib in python?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

```
You probably meant to install and run ta-lib
```

And indeed, [the description on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/talib/) says that `talib` is "a package to prevent exploit".

A look at the [package source](https://pypi.org/project/talib/#files) confirms this because it contains nothing more than a couple of stubs that return "You probably meant to install ta-lib".

To install the "real" ta-lib, you should run `pip install ta-lib`.